# Given a list of type-differing objects with the same base class, how could a completely separate class manipulate each, without if/else logic?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

**Context:**
The following pseudo-code example demonstrates a [anti-]pattern that is present throughout my project. This C# example code was quickly typed up, so forgive any mistakes.

**Challenge:**
I am trying to avoid branching as much as possible (if/else, switch/case) in the pursuit of a using good OOP practices, such as polymorphism and single responsibility.

**Setup of example classes:**

```
class Person {
    public string Name;
}

class Employee : Person {
    public int EmployeeID;
}

class Customer : Person {
    public int CustomerID;
}

class PersonDao {
    public void Save(Person person){
    // .. save Person to database
    }
}

class EmployeeDao : PersonDao {
    public override void Save(Person employee){
    // .. save Employee to database
    }
}

class CustomerDao : PersonDao {
    public override void Save(Person customer){
    // .. save Customer to database
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

```
Person person = new Person{ Name="Frank" };
Person employee =  new Employee{ Name="Alice", EmployeeID=5678};
Person customer = new Customer{ Name="Nellie", CustomerID=123};

PersonDao personDao = new PersonDao();
EmployeeDao employeeDao = new EmployeeDao();
CustomerDao customerDao = new CustomerDao();

List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
people.Add(person);
people.Add(employee);
people.Add(customer);

foreach (Person person in people){
    if (person.GetType() == typeof(Person)) 
        personDao.Save(person);
    else if (person.GetType() == typeof(Customer)) 
        customerDao.Save(person);
    else if (person.GetType() == typeof(Employee)) 
        employeeDao.Save(person);
}
```

**Question in detail:**
Looking at the contents of the foreach loop with its asking each object what type it is seems completely antithesis to the idea of polymorphism.  My first reaction is to offer each Person class the ability to Save() itself.  However, this would seem too much responsibility for the class.

I suppose there could also be some intermediary class that hides this branching away elsewhere, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to do this without any if/else at all.

What design pattern or architectural failure am I missing here?  How would you have programmed this, given subclasses of Person need to be saved or otherwise manipulated by a separate class?

Comment: What is the meaning behind creating `Person` object (_`Person person = new Person{ Name="Frank" };`_)? Maybe it should be abstract?

Comment: I don't know how your dao classes are implemented but if they could implement a generic interface it would save you a lot of trouble. Such as `Dao<Customer>`.

Comment: @SeM True, the base class could be purely abstract or an interface.  I see now that it was an unnecessary detail to add an instance of Person to the mix.  The real question concerns the sibling classes:  Employee and Customer.

Comment: @Halex I'll admit I've only recently begun learning about generics, so I would need to research that.

Comment: In this case you would have a simple interface `Dao<T>` with a method `Save(T person)` which you can then implement as you need. Then you could do something like `GetDao(typeof(person).Save(person)`.

Comment: Its possible that part of my design flaw is putting mixed class objects in the same list in the first place.  Maybe everyone else keeps strict boundaries on where their objects are placed depending on how they're used?

Comment: @Halex Ah ok, I see what you mean.  That would follow the "Tell don't ask" principle.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally there is nothing wrong with this code, until it isn't spread across your code base. In this case it's better to refactor somehow.

Natural OOP way of doing this — adding virtual `Save` method to a `Person` class and overriding it in all the descendants. But we will obviously violate multiple design principles by doing this.

For this reason, there is a [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern, which allows you to add custom operations to existing data structure.

It could be implemented in this way for your scenario.

```
public interface IPersonVisitor
{
    void Visit(Person person);
    void Visit(Employee employee);
    void Visit(Customer customer);

    /*Visit method overload for every item in hierarchy*/
}
```

Method accepting visitor in hierarchy base class

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name;

    public virtual void Accept(IPersonVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}
```

Overrided in all the descendants

```
public class Employee : Person
{
    public int EmployeeID;

    public override void Accept(IPersonVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}
```

And actual implementation of the operation for every type

```
public class DaoPersonVisitor: IPersonVisitor
{
    public void Visit(Person person)
    {
        var personDao = new PersonDao();
        personDao.Save(person);
    }

    public void Visit(Employee employee)
    {
        var employeeDao = new EmployeeDao();
        employeeDao.Save(employee);
    }

    public void Visit(Customer customer)
    {
        var customerDao = new CustomerDao();
        customerDao.Save(customer);
    }
}
```

Then you could call it in this way

```
var person = new Employee();
person.Accept(new DaoPersonVisitor());
```

Overload resolution will play its role and `DaoPersonVisitor.Visit(Emploee)` will be called.

Visitor is a good fit when we want to add some specific operation to a hierarchy, but it looks like an overkill for your case, because visitor itself doesn't contain any specific logic — chooses appropriate DAO object and nothing more.

Probably, moving DAO selection logic to a single place will be enough, as it will remove all the duplication.

You will need interface or base class for your DAO types, implementing it in all the descendants.

```
public interface IPersonDao
{
    void Save(Person person);
}
```

And a factory class (or just a method, if this logic could be placed in some class boundaries) which returns appropriate DAO

```
public static class PersonDaoFactory
{
    public static IPersonDao Create(Person person)
    {
        if (person is Employee)
        {
            return new EmployeeDao();
        }

        if (person is Customer)
        {
            return new CustomerDao();
        }

        /* cases for all the other object in hierarchy */

        throw new NotSupportedException($"Can't create DAO for '{person.GetType().FullName}'. Type is not supported.");
    }
}
```

Then you could simply call this method in all the places, where DAO should be chosen based on person type — it means there is no duplication.

Comment: This is beautiful, thank you!! I had recently learned the Visitor pattern but had not thought of it for this purpose.  What you've added here is all excellent material for to work with.

Comment: @user2075962 this article may be interesting btw, as visitor is in category of multimethods or dynamic dispatch https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem

Comment: I'll check that out.  Thanks again!

Comment: Nice answer!
Why override Accept in descendants if it contains exactly what base class does?

Comment: @Lamelas84 it's required for proper overload resolution in Visitor class. Otherwise `DaoPersonVisitor.Visit(Person)` will be always called. A bit a lot of boilerplate, so it's possible to use some kind of hack with `dynamic` for shorter visitor 
implementation in c#, but performance could suffer.

Answer (score 0):

What if you make it generic like below

```
class EntityDao<T> : PersonDao {
    public override void Save(T employee){
    // .. save Employee to database
    }
}
```

Then you can probably do like

```
EntityDao<Employee> dao = new EntityDao<Employee>();
dao.Save(emp);
```

Comment: This is similar/same to what Halex commented, though he determines the Dao by using typeof on the target object.  If there are no other answers, I'll mark yours as the solution.  I still feel like there could/should be a different way or that I'm missing something else fundamental.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not a pure SOLID answer but an idea:

You can declare a new interface to your DAO objects:

```
interface PersonSaver
{
    void Save(Person person);
}

class PersonDao : PersonSaver {
    public void Save(Person person){
    // .. save Person to database
    }
}

class EmployeeDao : PersonSaver {
    public void Save(Person employee){
    // .. save Employee to database
    }
}

class CustomerDao : PersonSaver {
    public void Save(Person customer){
    // .. save Customer to database
    }
}
```

Then you can include the PersonSaver each class must use:

```
class Person {
    public string Name;
    public virtual PersonSaver Saver
    {
        get
        {
            return new PersonDao();
        }
    }
}

class Employee : Person {
    public int EmployeeID;
    public override PersonSaver Saver
    {
        get
        {
            return new EmployeeDao();
        }
    }
}

class Customer : Person {
    public int CustomerID;
    public override PersonSaver Saver
    {
        get
        {
            return new CustomerDao();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, this would be your foreach block:

```
foreach (Person person in people){
    person.Saver.Save();
}
```

Comment: It's not SOLID. This violates S because the model is responsible for saving and D because model is higher abstraction component so it should not reference a lower abstraction component.

Comment: This goes in the direction of having the object save itself and you did it in a better way than I would have managed. Thank you.  Although I still feel it adds too much responsibility to the object itself.